# How to add point on every line ( ohlcv plotted as line) change in mplfinance?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plot, yahoo-finance, mplfinance

[image]

I'd like to plot a image like the one above (photoshopped).

I tried using `mpf.make_addplot(data,type='scatter')`, but the dataframe (data) dont match the line.

The line represents the middle of the candle so i thought about making a list with all halves of the candles and then applying points in those coordinates, but i am sure there is a better method
Is there a way to solve and automate this?

**Some code:**

```
import mplfinance as mpf

# Here i get the dataframe from yahoo and get the last 50 candles

savefig = dict(fname="test.jpg", bbox_inches="tight")
mpf.plot(data, type='line', axisoff=True, savefig=savefig)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can [see from the code here](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/src/mplfinance/plotting.py#L397-L400) `type=line` plots the `close` price, *not* the middle of the candle as you thought.

Therefore `mpf.make_addplot(data,type='scatter')` should work for you, if you pass in the `close` prices to `make_addplot()`.